# System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Authenticator' threw an exception

Tags: authentication, dynamics-crm, adal, server-to-server

I'm attempting to perform S2S authentication from a Dynamics 365 plugin, unsuccessfully so far. The following exception occurs:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Authenticator' threw an exception
```

My understanding is that the exception is thrown at the time when IdentityModel dll gets loaded, not even during runtime. However, if that matters, here is what we are doing in code:

```
var clientCreds = new ClientCredential(clientId, secret);

AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUri);
AuthenticationResult authResult = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCreds).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

We are using the following packages:

The same code works in a console app. Any help/suggestions are very appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to S2S to?

Comment: To a web api service in Azure

Answer (score 0):

This might be because you are running in the sandbox. Whilst the MSDN doesn't explicity advise against this, it recommends you only connect to anonymous services.

[Plug-in isolation, trusts, and statistics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334752.aspx)

> Access to the file system, system event log, certain network protocols, registry, and more is prevented in the sandbox.
>
> ...
>
> Sandboxed plug-ins and custom workflow activities can access the
>   network through the HTTP and HTTPS protocols....The following web
>   access restrictions apply to this sandbox capability.
>
> - Anonymous authentication is supported and recommended.